# How to select partition name of specific data?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, partition

I want to select a data and wanna see in which partition.

> partition column is : code (varchar column)

```
Select .... -- I want to find partition name
from
partition_table
where to_number(code) = 55;
```

why I need to this:

I have a data which code is '55' but in that table when I use partition column I do not select it. But there is data which value is '55'

So I want to that data in which partition.

And the data is not in **PDEFAULT** partition. I ve already check it.

### edit

data is in another partition. I think there is a problem with exchange partition process

thanks in advance

Comment: You can also use `select ... from partition_table PARTITION FOR ('55')` - then you don't have to know the partition name.

Comment: the data is not in '55' partition. İt is in different partition

Comment: Then I don't understand your question, please elaborate and provide some sample data.

Comment: I think there is a problem with exchange  partition process

Comment: Now you confused me even more...

Comment: I edit my question. data is in partition '44' .

Comment: Will this answer help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329384/oracle-sql-selecting-data-and-partition-name-from-table-and-truncating-partitio

Comment: Are you looking for this? `SELECT PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PARTITION_TABLE'`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways.

1) The rowid will point to the partition object

```
SQL> create table t ( x int, y int )
  2  partition by range (x )
  3    ( partition p1 values less than ( 100 ),
  4      partition p2 values less than ( 200 )
  5    );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t values (34,34);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> select rowid from t;

ROWID
------------------
AAA0cqAAHAAAAQ6AAA

1 row selected.

SQL>
SQL> select dbms_rowid.rowid_object(rowid) from t;

DBMS_ROWID.ROWID_OBJECT(ROWID)
------------------------------
                        214826

1 row selected.

SQL>
SQL> select subobject_name
  2  from user_objects
  3  where data_Object_id =
  4   ( select dbms_rowid.rowid_object(rowid) from t );

SUBOBJECT_NAME
------------------------------------------------------------
P1
```

2) You can data mine the dictionary to probe the HIGH_VALUE column in USER_TAB_PARTITIONS.  I did a video on how to do that here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKHQQXKdfOM